# Invalid request sqlite android

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, sqlite

sorry for my english. It is impossible to make a valid request to update the data. 
That's works:

```
    "UPDATE " + Names.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Names.NamesColumns.FNAME + " = '" 
+ comment + "' WHERE " + BaseColumns._ID + " = " + l
```

But I need to modify the two fields:

```
    "UPDATE " + Names.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Names.NamesColumns.NAMEDREAM
    + " = " + context + "," + Names.NamesColumns.DESCRIPTION + " = '" + description + "'
 WHERE " + BaseColumns._ID + " = " + l
```

as well adding to the request for a new value here gives such errors:

> 11-02 11:17:54.982: E/SQLiteLog(1479): (1) near "@53518c2c": syntax
>   error 11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479): Failed open database. 
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@53518c2c": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Dreams SET nameDream =
>   android.app.ContextImpl@53518c2c,description = 'ZXC' WHERE _id = 12
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) 11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   database.Controller.update(Controller.java:80) 11-02 11:17:54.986:
>   E/Controller(1479):   at
>   com.example.firstv.ComplateDreams$2$1.onClick(ComplateDreams.java:92)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-02
>   11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-02 11:17:54.986:
>   E/Controller(1479):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 11-02
>   11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-02
>   11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-02 11:17:54.986:
>   E/Controller(1479):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   11-02 11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 11-02
>   11:17:54.986: E/Controller(1479):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the content of your strings looks like. But it seems you've forgotten to wrap the context string in single quotes. That might be it.

```
"UPDATE " + Names.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Names.NamesColumns.NAMEDREAM
    + " = '" + context + "'," + Names.NamesColumns.DESCRIPTION + " = '" + description + "'
 WHERE " + BaseColumns._ID + " = " + l
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (wrap context into ' ')?

```
"UPDATE " + Names.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Names.NamesColumns.NAMEDREAM
    + " = '" + context + "'," + Names.NamesColumns.DESCRIPTION + " = '" + description + "'
 WHERE " + BaseColumns._ID + " = " +
```